# Hitting requests with different IPs in a virtual machine

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, api-testing, aws

My jmeter setup is installed in a virtual machine, I want to hit requests such that they appear to come from different IPS. Need a possible solution if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler provides a special field to set source IP address:

[image]

so you can create a list of IP addresses, put them into a CSV file and use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) so each request would go from a different IP.

Just be aware of one constraint: the IP address (or at least an [IP alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing))must be present in the operating system so you need to perform the necessary configuration for your operating system.

See [IP Spoofing With JMeter: How to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ip-spoofing-jmeter) article for more details.

Also the approach will work for local intranet, if you're behind the [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) and the target system is in the Internet - it will see requests coming from one address only.

Comment: Is it possible to do in EC2 machines?

Comment: EC2 machine isn't different from any other machine